# What does it mean to describe someone as a butt steak?

Tags: dialogue, the-shawshank-redemption

In *The Shawshank Redemption*, the officer said to a prisoner:

> Do you speak English, **butt-steak**?

What does it mean to describe someone as a butt-steak?

Comment: For what it's worth, just about any noun could have served the same purpose as long as the tone of the delivery was the same. English is a mighty language :)

Comment: The context is quite important.  If it were Tina Belcher using the term the meaning would be completely different.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The key word is "butt".  It's like calling someone an ass, but in a way that has a double meaning so as not to get in trouble from your superiors for using foul language.  A butt steak is another term for top sirloin, so that's the double meaning.  It was clearly meant as a veiled insult.

Comment: Or perhaps a _vealed_ insult.

Comment: Is top sirloin bad?

Comment: @AzorAhai it's not _bad_ but it's certainly not the best cut. ("Best cut" is subjective but I'm not sure of any criteria that would put sirloin at the _ahem_ "top" of the list)

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Actually, *most* lists have Fore Rib, Sirloin, Top Rump and Fillet listed at the top, as the best cuts.  (And "top sirloin" is a pointless name, since it comes from the French "surloinge", where "sur" means "above" or "top"...  And, Americans use a different set of names for the cuts compared to the rest of the world, calling sirloin "short loin" and rump "sirloin" >_<)

Comment: @Chronocidal I was confused by this very much, moving from the UK to the USA, sirloin is a cheap cut here, which roughly (though not exactly) corresponds with what the UK called rump steak. In the UK sirloin was a fairly nice and expensive cut. Honestly US cuts of beef are almost unrelated to those of any other countries I know.

Comment: Since when does "ass" not have a double meaning?

Comment: @Owen - Yes, there are plenty I could have used instead of ass (the only single-meaning words I could think up were WAY too offensive), but I was trying to keep it appropriate.

Comment: @pipe ahhhhh this should be an answer so i can +1!

Answer (score 17):

Some hearsay for you...  I had a friend that was in the military (in the 60's) and he told me that superiors were not allowed to insult lower ranking troops so they would use "creative" names and acronyms that technically had a non-insulting meaning but everyone knew it was just a veiled insult.

For instance, they would call people a TURD which is another word for poop, but they said it was actually an [acronym that meant](https://www.allacronyms.com/TURD/military_slang) "Trainee Under Rigid Discipline".  Now that's not an insult - it's just a descriptive classification.

Police, prison guards, and the military share some culture.  This could be seen as another way of calling the prisoner an ass (bad word for butt), but *not really*.

Comment: You can stick "butt" before just about any word and it becomes an insult. "butt-head" and "butt-wad" are common (the latter literally means toilet paper left behind in your butt).

Comment: @Barmar, right, but the point is that a "butt steak" is a real thing you can go to the grocery store and ask for with a straight face. Just adding butt to a word is a "real" insult.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely he was trying to subtly let him know that he was going to be treated like a piece of meat.  Andy was supposed to be a fairly good looking man, and in male prisons, "pretty boys" were highly prized.  Steak was considered highly sought after back then, so it's implied that he will be very desirable in the prison.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing much deep here, it's just a plain insult.

Generally, Steak is :

> meat generally sliced across the muscle fibers, potentially including a bone. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak)

So butt-steak means sliced meat from a butt and is used just to insult.